# better merge way: `rebase -i`(squash)&`merge --no-ff` VS `merge --squash` VS `rebase`

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, squash

better merge way: `rebase -i`(squash)&`merge --no-ff` VS `merge --squash` VS `rebase`

Premise:

- Follow github-flow
- Branches other than main will eventually be deleted
- But there will be merges several times before then

What I heard:

- Avoid `rebase` on public branches
- Avoid force push
- Make a merge commit for every merge
- Make it possible to identify which branch each commit is from

(I'm not even sure if these are correct...)

About merging in a feature branch and main branch, what are the pros and cons of each method when

- if the work in the feature branch is still in progress
- if the work in the feature branch is all done and waiting to be deleted after the merge

I've heard "use squash merge", but I'm confused because there are several ways!

Comment: Which is the best flavor of ice cream? What's the best kind of car? Which is better, city or country living? Apartment or house?

Comment: @torek I understand that these kinds of questions are ultimately "case by case". However, it can take a beginner a long time just to choose one thing from the menu. It would be helpful to have some advice from someone who is familiar with it at that time. What do you recommend?

Comment: True enough. I recommend doing some experimenting, because different people find different work flows work best for them. They also find that their favorite work flow will evolve. To *start*, I suggest making a lot of tiny (one or two changes at a time) commits and using `git rebase -i` to combine them into more-sensible commits, because it's a lot easier to combine commits than to split them.